# List Foreach parameterized delegate

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to invoke a function for every member of a list, but pass additional parameters to the delegate.

if I have a list called `documents`

```
List<string> documents = GetAllDocuments();
```

Now I need to iterate over the documents and call a method for every entry. I can do it using something like

```
documents.ForEach(CallAnotherFunction);
```

This would require the `CallAnotherFunction` to have a definition like

```
public void CallAnotherFunction(string value)
{
    //do something
}
```

However, I need another parameter in `CallAnotherFunction` called, say `content`, that is dependent on the calling list.

So, my ideal definition would be

```
public void CallAnotherFunction(string value, string content)
{
    //do something
}
```

And I would like to pass content as part of the ForEach call

```
List<string> documents = GetAllDocuments();
documents.ForEach(CallAnotherFunction <<pass content>>);

List<string> templates = GetAllTemplates();
templates.ForEach(CallAnotherFunction <<pass another content>>);
```

Is there a way I can achieve this without having to define different functions, or use iterators?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use lambda expressions instead of method groups:

```
List<string> documents = GetAllDocuments();
documents.ForEach( d => CallAnotherFunction(d, "some content") );

List<string> templates = GetAllTemplates();
templates.ForEach( t => CallAnotherFunction(t, "other content") );
```

Comment: Man- I feel dumb, that was too obvious. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Use lambda expression:

```
string content = "Other parameter value";
documents.ForEach(x => CallAnotherFunction(x, content));
```